# Логика условия jquery

Tags: jquery

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при том, когда страница = [https://домен](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD) или адрес содержал слово rid , то выполнялось условие 1 иначе условие 2 (1 и 2 берем условно)
вот мой код, но он не работает правильно

```
 <script>
let url_string = window.location.toString();
let url = new URL(url_string);
let rid = url.searchParams.get("?rid=");
$(function(){
if(typeof rid !== "undefined"){
        $('#obmenpl').removeClass('col-lg-6');
$('.downbar').css('display', 'block');
$('.lobmen_widget').css('display', 'block');
}else {}
});
</script>

  <script>
    var a = window.location.toString();
    $(function() {
        if (a === 'https://www.ok24pay.com/'  ) {
            $('.downbar').css('display', 'block');

        } else {
                $('#obmenpl').removeClass('col-lg-6');
            $('.downbar').css('display', 'none');
            $('.lobmen_widget').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  let url = new URL(window.location);
  // only in parameters following "?":
  let rid = url.searchParams.get("rid");
  if (rid != null) {
    console.log("has rid in search parameters");
  } else {
    console.log("no rid in search parameters");
  }
});

$(function() {
  var a = window.location.toString();
  if (a.toLowerCase().startsWith('https://www.ok24pay.com')) {
    console.log("on page https://www.ok24pay.com");
  } else {
    console.log("not on page https://www.ok24pay.com");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: поиск слова rid, неверно что ли?

Comment: @EmilRotatew Не понял вопроса.

Comment: второй скрипт смотрит, если пользователь на этой странице то делать следующие манипуляции (я думаю неважно что именно)